PNG investigation software: byte values of RGBA channels for any desired pixel
I need a simple application like Windows Paint, but showing me these values for each pixel that I select:

Red byte value
Green byte value
Blue byte value
Alpha or transparency byte value

I need it to analyze an image by investigating the 4 bytes of the RGBA channels for any desired pixel:


If you are interested in java, there are many ways to set up a program for yourself (and I guess the same holds for most modern programming languages). You can also use a tool to convert the image to pmn-format.

@GyroGearloose I was not aware of the pmn file format for images. Thanks.

Many paint & image editing tools include that capability to measure the RDBA value at a given point, one good free example is GIMP - which includes a dropper tool to sample point colours.

Of course if you need to automate your investigation then you could possibly use a combination of Python, Pillow & Numpy as is shown here.

Thanks. I'm going to try it. The good thing is GIMP is opensource :)

@Megidd - of course it can also do a lot of other things.

I tried it. It was just what I needed.
